# How to restrict date and time in django bootstrap datetimepicker plus?

Tags: jquery, django, django-forms, bootstrap-datetimepicker

i am newbie using jquery stuff and date time picker.
i am using https://github.com/monim67/django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus in my django forms . User cannot pick date more then next two days and cannot select time from 18:00 to 8:00 . how to manage all this . i had used jquery in it but didn't accomplished 
for eg

1. today is 22june
2. user can select date till 24june
3. time user can see is from 8:00 to 17:00

   **Forms.py**

   ```
   class BookingForm(ModelForm):

      class Meta:
          model = Booking
         widgets = {
         'times_pick': DateTimePickerInput(), }
         fields = ('booking_name','rental_price','book_car','customer_name','times_pick',)
   ```

can anyone tell me how to use jquery to customize it like i told before.
please help me out

Answer (score 2):

All you need is a combination of `minDate`, `maxDate` and `enabledHours` options.

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Booking

import datetime


class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ('booking_name', 'rental_price',
                'book_car', 'customer_name', 'times_pick',)
        widgets = {
            'times_pick': DateTimePickerInput(
                options={
                    'minDate': (datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00'),
                    'maxDate': (datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=2)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59'),
                    'enabledHours': [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
                }
            ),
        }
```